# upload.aspx inheriting custom masterpage

Tags: 2013, master-page, file-upload

I have been developing a custom master-page based off of SharePoint 2013 html to master page converter. The SharePoint site will be used as a simple document portal for customers.

My problem comes when a user tries to upload a document, the document upload page inherits the custom master-page but does not display properly in the iframe popup. I am happy with the default upload page and if possible would like to use it.How can I achieve this.

This is how the document upload iframe looks currently

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid applying your customizations to dialogs add the CSS class `s4-notdlg` to all HTML elements you want to hide.

If you are applying custom CSS to standard HTML elements you'd need to use the CSS class `ms-dialog` to reset them to their respective default values.

If you need help to identify those elements either post the relevant code or use tools like F12 Developer Tools (Internet Explorer), Firebug (Firefox) or the built-in Chrome developer tools.

**UPDATE**

Also, from your screen capture, you probably applied CSS width and height values to the body of your HTML masterpage. If so, you need to reset those values using the `ms-dialog` CSS class to clear them.

If you are unsure which changes are causing the size issues just post your HTML code and we can analyse it together.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding the css classes to my html worked and I was able to remove everything from the page. I am left now with a mostly blank page except for the upload box, is there a way to change the sizing. (see image)

http://i.imgur.com/yMbuGcj.png

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it, this has had me stumped for the last couple of days. I was able to get it figured out by resetting my widths with the ms-dialog like you said.